# Laravel: Find not my Model in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, model, controller

I have a little Laravel problem.
I wrote a controller and a model. The model was created via artisan. But my controller does not find the model and I can not create an instance. I'm sure it's pretty easy. However, I am quite inexperienced.

My model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quote extends Model
{

}
```

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Quote;//Import is never used
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class QuoteController extends Controller{
    $quote = new Quote();//PHPStorm does not find the class


    public function postQuote(Request $request){

    }


    public function getQuotes(){

    }


    public function putQuote(Request $request, $id){

    }


    public function deleteQuote($id){

    }



}
```

My Repo on Github:

https://github.com/TheSlowlySnail/LaravelRestTutorial

I'll try this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4uajiXW5R3o&t=614s

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please try placing this "$quote = new Qutoe();" inside any function not outside?

Comment: And in you library at url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TheSlowlySnail/LaravelRestTutorial/master/app/Http/Controllers/QuoteController.php spelling of Quote is incorrect see this "$quote = new Qutoe();"

Comment: You say "PHPstorm doesn't find the class". Do you mean your IDE doesn't find it, or PHP doesn't find it? The first is annoying but has nothing to do with the second.

Comment: So embarrassing. You are my hero :)

Comment: You can not initialize a model object outside of any class method. This is why your IDE is unable to find out that model class

Comment: @Helge: Please use *$quote = new Quote();* in inside the function and try

Answer (score 0):

You can only instantiate an object within a controller method.
so your example would probably be the along the lines of the following:

```
public function postQuote(Request $request)
{
    Quote::create($request->all());
}

public function getQuotes()
{
    $quotes = Quote::get();
}

public function putQuote(Request $request, $id)
{
    Quote::find($id)
        ->update($request->all());
}

public function deleteQuote($id)
{
    Quote::find($id)->delete();
}
```

This code is for example purposes but hopefully gives you more understanding as to how laravel models and facades work